# Stream video from QCamera or QMediaPlayer through OpenGL shader in Qt5/C++

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5, shader

The excellent [QML Video Shader Effects Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimedia-video-qmlvideofx-example.html) shows that feeding a video stream through an OpenGL fragment-shader (GLSL) is trivial in QML.

What I want to know is, how can the same be accomplished using only **C++** instead of relying on **QML**? What `Qt5` classes should I use to have video from `QCamera` or `QMediaPlayer` stream into an OpenGL texture that is rendered on geometry with a fragment-shader applied?

My naïve guess would be something like this:

1. Create and set up [QOpenGLWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html) instance
2. Create and set up [QOpenGLTexture](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopengltexture.html) instance
3. Create and set up video source instance ([QCamera](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcamera.html) or [QMediaPlayer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#details))
4. Set up [QVideoProbe](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoprobe.html) to capture individual frames and...
5. ...feed frame data from the probe into texture using one of the texture's many `setData()` member functions
6. At [paintGL()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#paintGL) time I would render some geometry using a [QShaderProgram](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qshaderprogram.html) program that samples the texture.

The reason why I don't jump on this approach straight away is that it includes a very expensive copy and even potential conversion operation for the frame pixels. In modern hardware, video decompression would often be done on GPU, and zero copy would be possible.

I suspect that in the QML implementation there is some optimizations like this, and I am hoping for an answer that provides a way to expose that level of optimizations to the C++ developer.

Comment: You can avoid copying only for data that already in GPU memory. But the camera doesn't stream data to GPU directly. Also, usually cameras do not compress stream, so there are no need to decompress it. BTW, video stream copying not that expensive.